# Confluent platform Kafka Connect crashed with Exit 137

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

On Mac, I pulled latest docker images. As I run stack, everything seems to be okay but "Connect" crashed with Exit 137.

When I looked at the command center, cluster health seems to be fine. What is the impact of this? How to correct the problem ?

[image]

Appreciate any help.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you post the output of the logs for the Connect docker container?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't tell me why it crashed.. below is what I get 

[2019-09-04 23:17:19,266] INFO Loading plugin from: /usr/share/java/confluent-control-center (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
bash: line 1:     6 Killed                  /etc/confluent/docker/run

Comment: How much memory do you have allocated to Docker? `docker system info | grep Memory`

Answer (score 27):

Error 137 is indicative of out-of-memory.

To run Confluent Platform you must allocate a minimum of 8 GB of Docker memory resource.

E.g. the default memory allocation on Docker Desktop for Mac is 2 GB and must be changed.

Comment: Not sure if this is connected, but 137 is a [reserved exit code](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) that indicates the program was killed by a SIGKILL signal. An out of memory error will likely cause this, but it is not the only cause. Of course, Confluent Kafka may not use the error code to represent this.

Comment: The OS sends SIGKILL to kill process that hits the cgroup memory limit. 137 is indicative of a processes killed by OS because of OOM. I don't think that the process sets that code (or has any chance of doing that). It is OS that assigns the code.